# Submitting a form with multiple submit values

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a voting webapp I'm building in PHP, and I'm looking for a straightforward solution to this simple problem (quite a fun problem I think!):

The voting form requires you to enter your email address to vote. I need each vote option to be a submit button.

In pseudo HTML it would look like this:

```
<form>
  <input type=email>
  <input type=submit name=voteOption1 value=VOTE> 
  <input type=submit name=voteOption2 value=VOTE>
  <input type=submit name=voteOption3 value=VOTE>
</form>
```

This works fine except for one thing: You will have noticed that the `value` for each of the submit buttons is VOTE - **this cannot be changed**. So I get the following from the server:

```
[email] => hello@example.com
[voteOption1] => VOTE
```

I need to know which option they voted for (eg. `voteOption1`). **Yes, the HTML can be changed.**

How would you solve this?

Comment: They voted for `voteOption1`, which is the key that gets passed to your form handler. That's the most straightforward answer, no?

Comment: question is, how is that code generated? Dynamically no doubt, so you'd probably need to post that. You could probably use a key to array method. If it's not generated dynamically, then why not just set different values? Bit unclear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an HTML 4 submit button instead of an HTML 3.2 one. Then you can have a different value and display text.

```
<button name="vote" value="Option 1">
    VOTE
</button>
```

Comment: True, yet what if their form is dynamically generated? The question's unclear as far as that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. Another way to solve this is to send a form array. For example:

```
<form>
  <input type=email>
  <input type=hidden name=voteOption1[option] value=voteOption1>
  <input type=submit name=voteOption1[submit] value=VOTE> 
  <input type=hidden name=voteOption2[option] value=voteOption2>
  <input type=submit name=voteOption2[submit] value=VOTE> 
  <input type=hidden name=voteOption3[option] value=voteOption3>
  <input type=submit name=voteOption3[submit] value=VOTE> 
</form>
```

So I get the following from the server:

```
[email] => hello@example.com
[voteOption1] => Array
    (
        [option] => voteOption1
        [submit] => VOTE
    )

[voteOption2] => Array
    (
        [option] => voteOption2
    )

[voteOption3] => Array
    (
        [option] => voteOption3
    )
```

Then you can simply look for the submit:

```
foreach ($submittedForm as $data) {
    if (array_key_exists ('submit', $data)) {
        $request->option = $data['option'];
        break;
    }
}
```

The downside to this is that all elements are submitted, but in this instance that's not a problem.

Comment: which kind of resembles what I suggested up there ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep, I was typing this answer as you were apparently writing your comment :)

Comment: Always nice to know it was useful ;-) *Cheers Chuck*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ha! Just so you know, I was already writing it AS you were writing your comment. It didn't inspire my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Am I getting it wrong or do you actually need to check which submit button is clicked?

```
if (isset($_POST['voteOption1']) {
    // VoteOption1 Clicked
} elseif (isset($_POST['voteOption2']) {
    // VoteOption2 Clicked
} elseif (isset($_POST['voteOption3']) {
    // VoteOption3 Clicked
}
```

Comment: My previous solution was similar to this, but it's pretty ugly and difficult to maintain.

Comment: of course it is ugly but it is the straight solution for this question.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type=submit name=voteOption1 value=VOTE1>
<input type=submit name=voteOption2 value=VOTE2>
```

etc..?

Comment: I believe their code is done dynamically and they didn't show it. I'm sure they thought of that though, but it needs to be built dynamically. Otherwise, they wouldn't have posted the question.

Comment: I hate downvotes without a comment to explain.
Reason I posted it was because it didn't already say in the question what could and couldn't be changed.

Comment: I agree there. You've gotten another downvote and can honestly say again that it is not mine.